# changing a document's theme using multiple index files

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a total of like 5 index.html files. They all have different index names and are linked to one JS file. When I click the button to change the theme of the index.html page. The theme changes to light theme and set in localStorage.  The other pages are not changed. Can someone get me in the right direction. What am I doing wrong?

```js
// Switch theme/add to local storage to all body elements in multiple .html files
const bodyElement = document.body
// Get the theme button via id
const themeToggleBtn = selectElement('#theme-toggle-btn');
//  passes the theme button to the toggleTheme function
const currentTheme = localStorage.getItem('currentTheme');

// checks if there is a current theme in local storage
if (currentTheme) {
    bodyElement.classList.add('light-theme');
}

//  event listener  btn is clicked the body element changes theme
themeToggleBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    bodyElement.classList.toggle('light-theme');

    //  checks if element has the class and sets it in local storage 
    if (bodyElement.classList.contains('light-theme')) {
        localStorage.setItem('currentTheme', 'themeActive');
        //  if not it removes it
    } else {
        localStorage.removeItem('currentTheme');
    }
});
```

```html
    <script src="./assets/js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your current code only applies the `light-theme` for pages that contain that script being served in the same domain only when the page is being loaded. In case you would like to apply the theme for already opened tabs you have to listen to the local storage changes. Is your question about synchronizing the theme between opened tabs ?

Comment: I may not understand the question. when i click the link to the resources tab in the nav bar it doesn't open a new tab, but changes the page/loads the new html.

Comment: However, it should still change no?

Comment: I did not post the whole snippet, but if you need to see the full code i can give you the link to the repository

Comment: It's pretty confusing, it would be better if you can share repository link. Then, I can detect the error more efficiently.